# How to properly pass data-id dynamically using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a custom context menu that should inherit the data-id value of the list item on which the right mouse button was clicked.

To be more explicit, I have an unordered list of countries. When a user right clicks on any one of these countries (list items), a context menu pop us. I want the data-id value to be passed on to the list items of the context menu.

According to what I see on the Elements inspector/windows, the data seems to be passed properly and successfully. On first click, the data-id is pulled successfully. However, when the user clicks on a second country, or rather list item, it still pulls the data-id of the first country the user right clicked on. What am I doing wrong?

This is how the file looks like:

```js
// When the ESC key is pressed,
$(document).bind("keyup", function(event) {
    // If ESC is pressed,
    if (event.keyCode == 27) {
        // Hide Context Menu
        $('.context-menu').hide();
        $('.context-menu').each(function() {
            $(this).find("li").each(function() {
                var current = $(this);
                current.removeAttr("data-id");
            });
        });
    }
});

// When user clicks on document,
$(document).on("click", function() {
    $('.context-menu').hide(); // hide context menu
    $('.context-menu').each(function() {
        $(this).find("li").each(function() {
            var current = $(this);
            current.removeAttr("data-id");
        });
    });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.members-list').on("contextmenu", "li", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var id = $(this).data("id");

        $('.context-menu').each(function() {
            $(this).find("li").each(function() {
                $(this).attr("data-id", id);
            });
        })

        $('.context-menu')
            .css({
                top: e.pageY + 'px',
                left: e.pageX + 'px'
            })
            .show();
    });

    $('.context-menu').on("click", "li", function() {
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        var action = $(this).data("action");
        switch (action) {
            case "view":
                alert("View: " + action + " " + id);
                break;
            case "edit":
                alert("Edit: " + action + " " + id);
                break;
            case "delete":
                alert("Delete: " + action + " " + id);
                break;
        }

        // Hide Context Menu
        $('.context-menu').hide();

        // Remove data id
        $('.users-menu').each(function() {
            $(this).find("li").each(function() {
                var current = $(this);
                current.removeAttr("data-id");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

```css
 *,
 *::before,
 *::after {
     margin: 0;
     padding: 0;
     outline: 0;
 }
 ul,
 ol {
     list-style: none;
 }
 .members-list li {
     color: ghostwhite;
     cursor: pointer;
     display: block;
     background: black;
     padding: 4px;
     margin-bottom: 2px;
 }
 .context-menu {
     display: none;
     padding: 2px;
     position: absolute;
     background: ghostwhite;
 }
 .context-menu li {
     padding: 6px;
     cursor: context-menu;
     border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
 }
 .context-menu li:last-child {
     border-bottom: 0;
 }
 .context-menu li:hover {
     color: ghostwhite;
     background: gray;
 }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <div class="members">
     <ul class="members-list">
      <li class="member" data-id="south-africa">South Africa</li>
      <li class="member" data-id="england">England</li>
     </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="context-menu">
     <ul class="context-menu-list">
      <li class="context-menu-item" data-action="view">
       <div class="menu-item">
        View Member
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" data-action="edit">
       <div class="menu-item">
        Edit Member
       </div>
      </li>
      <li class="context-menu-item" data-action="delete">
       <div class="menu-item">
        Delete Member
       </div>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
```

I have screen shots of the Elements inspection. Please find them below:
[image]

Comment: You should do some debugging yourself, e.g. narrow the example provided to the code that reproduces the bug.

Comment: You should put only relevant code.

Comment: Noted, Rajesh. Thank you. I will do that from here on.

Comment: Alex, I had tried to. But I was not winning, hence I came here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi Replace the following code

```
var id = $(this).data("id"); with var id =$(this).attr("data-id");
```

in after this line $('.context-menu').on("click", "li", function()

it will help you check that and tell me if you have any problems

Comment: Thanks, Hitesh. It worked. I appreciate your assistance.

Comment: God bless, it worked like a charm.